# Simplest Way to Serve Files - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the simplest way to serve files in Rails?

By this I mean: I'd like to go to, say, http://myserver.com/assets/arbitraryfile.arbitraryformat and have it just load `arbitraryfile.arbitraryformat` in the browser, letting the browser decide whether to download it or display it or whatever else. (In particular I plan to make a bookmarklet that invokes a *.js file from the server, which in turn loads a *.css file and downloads a font *.tty file from the same.)

Currently I've got an `assets` resources routing to an `assets#show` action, but I'm not at all sure how to code my `show`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd stream the data to the browser and let it do whatever it needs to do. You can use one of two rails methods to get what you want:

a) send_data

```
foo_data = "This is my data"
send_data(foo_data, filename: "foo_file.txt")
```

b) send_file (which allows you to use a path)

```
send_file("my_app/assets/public/pdf/my_pdf.pdf", type: "application/pdf")
```

Check out the [official doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html).

Comment: Hm. About 90% there, I think. Last bit - where's root? Is it just `(appname)`, the folder that contains `app` and `public` and whatnot? Is it `app\assets\`? I saw something somewhere else that indicated that if you just provided a filename it'd automatically search the `assets` folder for it but I'm not sure that's applicable here.

Comment: Umm... that's just an example URI. You'd use the path of whatever file you are trying to serve. You don't have to put your files where I wrote. I just thought that using a realistic looking path would be more illustrative than something like `foo/bar/baz/quz/my_pdf.pdf`. `my_app` in that example is the application root, not the actual root (of the filesystem). You can also use `Rails.root` to get your application directory so you can just append a relative path from that point.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's not what I meant. Where *is* the application root, is the question here? Rails is unintuitive enough for me that I'm not sure if it'll start looking from my `assets` folder or my actual root folder (the folder named `myapp`)

Comment: Eh? Rails looks where you tell it to look -- that's the point of using `send_file` and specifying a path. Are you maybe mixing up serving files (as we're discussing) with loading CSS, JS and other assets? I'm not aware of any automagic file search in the context that we're discussing.

Comment: ... there's a difference between loading "assets" and everything else?

Comment: ["Asset"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) has a specific meaning in the Rails world. Arbitrary files that have a semantic, but perhaps not technical, relationship with your application aren't Rails assets. BTW, you're running into the suck part of Rails. As long as you pay no attention to the man behind the curtain, Rails is great, but once you need to understand the magic, things can get convoluted.

Comment: I see. Then yeah, we're done here. Thanks for the help, that answered it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the methods above but it kept automatically downloading the files to disk, which wasn't what I wanted.

To get the file to be opened, and viewed, in the browser I had to move the file to the `public/` folder and then it will be accessible by going to `myappdomain.com/filename.pdf`